# Why are restic incremental backups slow on Windows?

Tags: backup, restic

I understand my first restic backup was slow because it uploaded gigabytes of data. Today I ran the backup command again. Few files have changed, but the predicted time is still longer than half an hour. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the FAQ warns, antivirus can slow restic on Windows. https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-restic-perform-so-poorly-on-windows

For me the solution was to exclude the process 'restic.exe' in Windows Defender:

[image]

Now trivial backups take 3 minutes

Comment: Indeed: 15 minutes to 3 minutes here... biggest improvement on folders with lots of small files!